# Why is this singular integral smooth

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

I have a question on the underlined part of a  statement on page 130  from the book "Analysis, by Lieb, and Loss":

[image]

My question is: I don't understand how the integral $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-\alpha}}dy$$ is smooth ? Why do I think it shouldnot be smooth?
Well, every time we take a derivative, the singularity becomes worse, and the integral  will no longer converge (beacause of a non-integrable singularity near $x$) after taking enough number of derivatives.
What am I missing here ? It is smooth for $x\notin supp f$, that is clear. What makes this more interesting is that the left hand side is indeed infinitely differentiable in $x$: The function $\hat{f}$ in
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{\dot{\imath}x\cdot y}\frac{\hat{f}(y)}{|y|^{\alpha}}dy$$
is a Schwartz function, and every derivative in $x$ will produce a polynomial that smoothes the singularity a little bit, and the singularity is locally integrable to begin with..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting $x-y\mapsto y$ gives
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-\alpha}}dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{f(x-y)}{|y|^{n-\alpha}}dy.$$
Then, since $f\in C_c^\infty$, one can differentiate with respect to $x$ by interchanging two limits.

Comment: Hi @eigenvalue. Notice the change of variables has been corrected.

Comment: @Medo Thanks for correcting mistakes.